# Other Ways for Riemann Zeta Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

A well-known way for analytic continuing riemann zeta function is using from the functional equation between $\zeta$, $\theta$ and $\Gamma$ function. but I know that there is or there are other ways for doing this analytic continuation. what are this ways?

Comment: How do you know they exist if you do not know what they are?

Comment: as i have in my mind in complex analysis stein's book it says that there are some other ways for doing it. @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Have a look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Representations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Titchmarsh, "The theory of the Riemann Zeta function", you can find 7 methods to prove the analytic continuation and the functional equation.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of other ways. Take for instance the following direct computation, similar to the Euler-MacLaurin's method. Assume first $s\in \mathbb C$ with $\Re s>1$. You 
have
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac{1}{n^s}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^s}
\right)+\frac1{s-1},
$$
and thus
$$
\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_n^{n+1}(n^{-s}-x^{-s}) d(x-n-1)
=\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_n^{n+1}s x^{-s-1}(n+1-x)dx.
$$
The rhs is obviously holomorphic for $\Re s>0$ (since $n+1-x\in [0,1]$). It is easy to go on (with more integration by parts) and prove that the rhs is in fact an entire function.